# WordPress adds paragraphs around shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, word-wrap

I'm trying to create an enclosing shortcode that should be inline with regular text. So I would like to use it like this:

`Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula [caption]elementum sed sit amet dui[/caption]. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.`

When doing this and saving the post, WordPress will automatically wrap paragraph tags **around** the shortcode. Like this:

`<p>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula</p><p>[caption]elementum sed sit amet dui[/caption]</p><p>. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.&nbsp;</p>`

What's the best way to disable this behaviour? Multiple people suggested moving the wp_autop filter to after the execution of the shortcode, but I believe this will only work for content **in the shortcode**, not for the wrapping of the shortcode itself.

Also, there's the [shortcode_unautop function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_unautop/) that should stop WordPress from wrapping the shortcodes, but I'm not sure if it works right, at least I can't seem to get it to work.

My shortcode now looks like this:

`function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<span class="caption">' . $content . '</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'caption', 'caption_shortcode' );`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shortcode_unautop()` function. For details check [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_unautop/).

Try like this:

```
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<span class="caption">' . shortcode_unautop($content) . '</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'caption', 'caption_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Right, there seems to be some difference when using your function; there's no new <p> inserted in front of the shortcode now, but after saving the post the paragraph is still being ended after the shortcode.